# get record by ueser id from mongo db Node, Express, TypeScript API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, oauth

I am building Node JS, Express with TypeScript api, where I want to get the data stored by a particular user. I want to get the reocrd from mongodb based on user ID.

My DataRouter.ts

```
router.get('/:userId', Data.findByUserId);
```

My Service.ts

```
async findByUserId(id: string): Promise<IRecord[]> {
        try {
            return await DataModel.find({userId: id});
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    },
```

My DataComponent

```
export async function findByUserId(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const record: IData[] = await DataService.findByUserId(req.params.id);

        res.status(200).json(record);
    } catch (error) {
        next(new HttpError(error.message.status, error.message));
    }
}
```

and my IRepository.ts

```
findByUserId(id: string): Promise<T[]>;
```

I am getting the error

> HttpError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value
> "auth0|5fa05bf7657a9f006f9be77d" at path "_id" for model "DataModel"

I will be very thankful if someone has experience it, and share your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the `userId` you pass to the `DataModel.find` method is not a valid ObjectId.

For some reason the objectId contains the prefix `auth0|`. Maybe you call the route with this parameter?

Comment: Yes this is my userID: userId
:
"auth0|5fa05bf7657a9f006f9be77d"

Comment: `auth0|` is not part of a mongoose UserId, that's why you get the error. Try it out without `auth0` and call the route just with 5fa05bf7657a9f006f9be77d as userId.

Comment: Status: 500

Name: Error

Error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "109024426039600041924" at path "_id" for model "DataModel"

Comment: This is still thinking on _id and it did not consider my userId

Comment: That's weird. If you pass in `5fa05bf7657a9f006f9be77d` and in the model call the userId seems to be `109024426039600041924` their is something more going on in between. You can try to debug and find the position, where the userId changed or simply print out the userId on the different levels of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Well you get an invalid Object ID as you can see in the error message `auth0|5fa05bf7657a9f006f9be77d`

where does `auth0|` come frome?

Also you could shorten your method to this:

```
findByUserId(id: string): Promise<IRecord[]> {
   return DataModel.find({userId: id});
},
```

Comment: Now I am geetng Null in result.

Comment: userId : "auth0|5fa05bf7657a9f006f9be77d" is is comming from 0Auth

Comment: @ZiaUllahZia yea, and thats an invalid mongodb ID